# Does and 95% CI containing 1 imply no difference in IRR calculations in the same was as in OR calculations?

Tags: confidence-interval, negative-binomial-distribution

My understanding is that with an odds ratio (OR) that a 95% CI containing 1 means that there is no difference between the odds of something occurring between groups. I wondered if this holds true for incident rate ratios (IRR)?

Many thanks,
Ewen

Comment: Your premise is false - a CI for an OR that includes 1 doesn't imply "no difference". It implies a failure to detect a difference. That may simply be lack of sample size for the size of the difference you have,

Answer (score 2):

I would have phrased this differently. The fact that the 95% confidence interval includes 1 means that you cannot reject the null hypothesis that the population parameter equals 1. Not being able to reject an hypothesis of no effect is not the same as confirming that there is no effect. It is [the difference between "absence of evidence" and "evidence of absence"](http://www.bmj.com/content/311/7003/485).

Otherwise, the null-hypothesis of "no effect" is indeed an IRR of 1 just as for an OR, as you suspected.

Comment: +1 I hope you will forgive my adding an appropriate link. If the OP is actually interested in providing evidence of absence, they might explore equivalence tests, e.g. [TOST](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/tost/info).